# Linux crontab command can replace java quartz

Tags: cron, quartz

I have a question about job schedular, can use crontab(linux) command replace java quartz?

I want to know the advantage of quartz, someone could give some advice.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the scale of the problem being solved, using the cron scheduler provided by Linux will work well for many problems (on a single host). When you would like some fail over capability quartz is going to be the solution. Quartz can act as a clustered scheduler. Configured correctly, one node could be brought down for patching while the jobs running on quartz continue to process. There are also features of quartz that cron does not provide. Persistence and disallowing concurrent execution are two that I am using for a project. Those are some of the features that stand out to me. It would be best to check the documentation and look at some of the examples provided.

Answer (score 0):

Cron is available by default on any unix based os. Quarz is simply a Java API with (more scheduling options). If you wish to schedule tasks within a Java application, Quartz is the way to go. If you wish to schedule adhoc os commands, unless you feel like writing your own generic scheduler, cron is the way to go.